# How to select a column from a file with command line

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file that appears as follow :

```
some random text : azoidfalkrnalrkazlkja
zlazekamzlekazmlekalzkemlkmlkmlkmlkmlkml
o&kjoik&oék"&po"éképo"k&éo"kéo"koé"kk"k"

Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
=======================================
  0       1      1000   No_Light X Disabled (Persistent)
  1       1      1010   Online   X E-Port 10:20:30:40:50:60:70:80 "some comment"
  2       1      1020   Online   X F-Port 10:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
  3       1      1030   No_Light X Disabled (Persistent)
```

I can extract all "Online" status with `grep "^ *[0-9].*Online" ./myfile`. How can I then extract further information for each line (for instance, add each value to a `$COLUMN` variable) ?
I would like to extract all data from the 3rd column, and then treat the result as an array to extract the data from each line.

**EDIT:** Quotting Jotne's Answer, I did somthing like that :

```
COLUMN=3
MYVARIABLE=($(awk '/Online/ {print $c}' c="$COLUMN" file))
echo ${MYVARIABLE[0]}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get information from eks column #3 and that is online:

```
COLUMN=3
awk '/Online/ {print $c}' c="$COLUMN" file
1010
1020
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I then select each line ? Does it work like an array ? (i.e. to select the 1st value : $VAR[0]) ?

Comment: I found how to do it. I will edit my OP to address this

Comment: This seems overly complex, when `awk '/Online/ {print $3}' file` would be sufficient...

Comment: @twalberg His solution allows for more modularity. I could use his function and just change the COLUMN variable (or read the value from an input) to get another result

Comment: @twalberg Its asked for a solution that reads the value from a variable named `$COLUMN`. If this was not the situation, you are correct.

Comment: @Jotne I fail to see how "for instance, add each value to a $COLUMN variable" means "read a value from the $COLUMN variable" - adding something to a variable is generally a write operation, not a read operation.